# Low accuracy classifying colors

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, svm

I'm doing some experiments for classifying images based on colors. I have a dataset of 9000 shoes images categorized in 9 color, 1000 images for each color.

I followed the [How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) tutorial of TensorFlow getting an accuracy of 58.3%.

Then I replaced the final layer with a SVC(RBF) classifier getting an accuracy of 65.4%.

Some errors are very debatable. For example, this image true label is `Brown` but my classifier says it is `Beige`:

[image: Brown]

But other errors are just errors. This image true label is `Pink` but my classifier says it is `Blue`:

[image: Blue]

How could I improve the accuracy? More images? Training the Inception network from scratch? Using "standard" ML and not Deep Learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inception is a NN model which was created to assign an image to some predefined class based on what item was in the image. It relies on many pooling/convolution layers to do the job and builds up features from lower-levels (edges) to higher-levels (eyes).

Nonetheless it is complex and powerful model, it can't do everything. Retraining will work properly only for similar tasks (like classifying different type of cars, differentiating between dogs/cats or flowers). You can't ask it whether something is eating or drinking, to add two numbers.

Ask yourself whether knowing the edges is the best thing to have if you want to learn the color of the shoes. Most probably no, but the number of times each color appear in this image is probably more important.

So I would try to cleanup images to have only shoes centered and then would try logistic regression.